# Java, Servlet, JSP and WAS compatibility

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, java-8, websphere

I am trying to upgrade JDK version of existing Enterprise application which is using below technologies;

- Java 6
- Servlet 2.4
- J2EE 1.4
- JSP 1.2
- WAS 8.5.5

I have upgraded WAS JDK from 6 to 8. I am able to build application using JDK 8, but when deploying EAR, I am getting `ClassCastException`.
The reason is when building, it somehow uses JSP 2.1 but in deployment older version of JSP related classes are loaded. How can I ask maven to use specific version of these technologies?
Also, I tried to upgrade these technologies to latest version but got many other Exception as its an huge code base.
If I am upgrading to newer technologies, what things I should consider?

Comment: Are you actually packaging the Java EE libraries in your app?  You shouldn't do that - just use the versions provided by the server.  Servlet and JSP, in particular, aren't compatible with a "bring your own implementation" setup, at least on WAS.

Comment: You need to mark all Java EE APIs in your maven build as `provided`. Make sure there is nothing from Java EE in your WEB-INF/lib. Also edit your quiestion with actual stacktrace from the exception.